# How can my users create a CNAME record to our site so we can reflect a page created by them?

Tags: javascript, express, dns, routes, cname

I work on Authstatus, a product of Authbase. We recently launched and we'd like a way for users to enter their domain into our site, and then point a CNAME record to, for example, `status.authbase.co`, and for us to route it to their status page.

Currently we use Cloudflare for DNS, and our domain is on the Gandi.NET network. We use a Node JS / Express JS backend.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

-William

Comment: who hosts the status page?

Comment: you can make use of cloudflare api's and do it. https://api.cloudflare.com/

Comment: @ShivajiVarma We currently host the status page, our system runs off've a DigitalOcean droplet.

Comment: you want your client domain eg: status.clientxyz.com to point to his status page hosted by your service?

Comment: @ShivajiVarma Yes, the status page is hosted under https://authbase.co/status/example

Comment: your client himself can create subdomains for his domain. you can't do anything, you can provide FAQ to users to do it manually. But if you want subdomain created in your dns server, eg: clientxyz.authbase.co, then you can make use following api( https://api.cloudflare.com/#dns-records-for-a-zone-create-dns-record ) and create it dynamically.